# ASP.NET TimeOut expired on: Membership.ValidateUser(username, password)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

The same copy of my asp.net web application running on another server keeps throwing this error every now and then:

*Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.*

The error occurs on the following **line 67**

```
Line 65: 
Line 66:         //determine if the user's username/password are valid
Line 67:         if (Membership.ValidateUser(userName, password))
Line 68:         {
Line 69:             userInfo = MembersDB.GetMemberByUserName(Login1.UserName);
```

Has anyone ever had this happen?

Also, it may be important to note that I have this very web application running on another server with more users but I don't have this *Connection Pool* issue

Comment: Which membership provider are you using?

Comment: The default Membership provider that comes with ASP.NET and uses AspNetDB.

Comment: A late comment but I also get this error. It seems that it has to do with the conenction to database. The strange thing is that any other data query to db loads fast but this specific action can timeout.

Answer (score 1):

I think that simply raising the maximum connection pool size should solve your problem, like so:

`Data Source=Server;Initial Catalog=TestDB;User ID=TestUser;`**`Max Pool Size=300`**